# How can I get Google Maps to show street names?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps used to show street names, all the way down to minor back roads if you zoomed in enough. Now, those seem to be gone. Is is possible that I've accidentally changed a setting that displays street names, or is this some bewildering new "feature" of some sort?

In response to the comments, here's a screenshot:

[image]

...and my browser info:

Google Chrome 18.0.under Mac OSX 10.6.8. Street labels sometimes appear at different zoom levels, but not always.

Comment: I still see street names. Can you give a screenshot or link to a specific map where you see this problem?

Comment: Agreed, like @WilliamJackson, I can see street names. More info will be needed to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Disable WebGL maps.

Comment: @dnbrv - How do I do that?

Comment: @neilfein: Open Google Maps and look at the bottom of the sidebar on the left.

Comment: I can't repro. I have WebGL enabled and I'm even looking at the same part of the map you are and I see street names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the screenshot (the zoom slider), you have WebGL enabled. It renders the visuals slightly differently and might bring some artifacts. (On my computer, the loading/rendering process looks strange but the end result is always working fine.)

To turn off WebGL in Google Maps, [open the site](http://maps.google.com) and look at the lower left corner of the screen (bottom of the side bar). There's the button labeled `Classic` - click it.

[image]

Note that disabling WebGL will also disable some of the features, such as 3D buildings and 45° imagery.

Answer (score 0):

For the updated Google Maps (2014), opt to go back to the old Google Maps. Click on the little gear looking icon at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Block your Flash player plugin on Google maps, in Firefox next to the back button.

Answer (score -3):

It's now called ROADS and is a LAYER - Usefully it's turned off.
You dont need to lose Glide (but I prefer it without anyway)

Comment: I'm not seeing a "Roads" layer. The "Labels" layer removes street names when using the Satellite view, but on the Map view the street names are there by default and "Labels" can't be de-selected.

Comment: My experience is the same as @AlEverett - DAve, can you post a screenshot of this on your end?